# VS 2013 ASP.NET can't modify the code while debugging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working with a ASP.NET 2.0 project that has been upgraded from vs 2005->2010->2013.

In vs 2005 and 2010 I can modify the code while debugging, save the changes, and reload the page with the changes applied.

Now in vs 2013 I can't do this. Can't change the code when I hit a breakpoint. Tried to activate all checkboxs in "Edit & Continue" options, but nothing worked.

It's annoying having to stop debugging and recompile the app to debug again the changes.

How can I solve this?

Comment: In 2012 you couldn't either. Sounds like a VB/C# thing. I think VB used to let you do that. I don't remember ever doing it with c#

Comment: Also does not work with 64bit apps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/10/12/how-to-edit-code-when-debugging-a-64-bit-application.aspx

Comment: I upgraded last year to VS2013 Express  for Web and also noticed Edit&Continue stopped working.  I can E&C projects created in VS2012 with VS2012, but if I open those projects in VS2013 E&C won't work.  I confirmed E&C is working in VS2013 by creating a new project in VS2013 and then E&C'ing - which worked fine.  There must be something in the .proj file that is preventing it from working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FINALLY figured it out. Here are my findings.

**To Reproduce:**
I created 2 vanilla projects:

```
1) .net 4.0 project with VS2012 (ProjectA) 

2) .net 4.5 project with VS2013 (ProjectB).
```

Then opened ProjectA with VS2013 and I couldn't Edit & Continue (E&C).

**Resolution:**

In VS2013, go into the project's properties on the "Build" tab and uncheck "Optimize Code".

I still don't know why I could Edit & Continue in VS2012 even with "Optimize Code" checked, but in VS2013, it won't work.

**Resources:**

Here is the link that aided me in locating the problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.debug.ENC.SupportedButNotAvaiable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Hope this helps!

Comment: VS 2017 proj props Build tab doesn't have Optimize Code

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but I found the answer today - at least one answer. I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 and in my case, attempting to debug an MVC 5 application. Switch your target platform (in the Build menu) from Any CPU to either *x64* for 64-bit or *x86* for 32-bit.

I ran into this today while attempting to debug my MVC 5 application. After reading the release notes for Visual Studio 2013, [including the fact that they added the ability in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx), I was puzzled. I checked my properties and saw that Optimize Code was unchecked while Edit & Continue were checked. The only other debugger marked was ASP.NET. On a hunch, I changed from targeting *Any CPU* to just targeting *x64* under the Build menu. After that, I was able to use Edit and Continue as long as I wasn't attempting to edit lambdas or other items!

Answer (score 1):

Find little solution for this case - close all files in solution before run debug.
Only files which were closed when debug is started can be edit.
Of file is opened when debug is start - edit is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, is the following:

1) Break point is hit, and I want to change code.

2) Now:   *Set next statement to somewhere earlier in the current function.*

3) Do the change

4) Save / CTRL-s

5) Stepping through the function now includes the change.