# ASP.NET website edit during debug stopped working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Environment: Win7 Pro, VS2013 Utimate, ASP.NET Website, VB.NET

I was for many months editing vb.net class modules and codebehind modules while running debug.

However, that stopped working a couple/three weeks ago, for no apparent reason.  Now, as soon as debug starts, the code is frozen.  I can still edit aspx pages, js and css, but not vb.net.

I originally thought this was an Edit and Continue problem however I've finally understood that Edit and Continue is really dynamic recompilation, where the newly edited code actually gets executed.
So this is different. This is in a website, which again, I finally understand is not "smart" enough to support Edit and Continue.

The best resolution I have is to open the website fresh from the file menu each time, bypassing the solutions file in the start window, which however omits all the settings from the previous debug settings.  Then I can edit during debug.  I can also delete the solutions file, which has the same effect, but is not necessary.  However, as soon as I save a new solutions file (VS asks for it every time) and reopen the site through that solutions file, I can no longer edit vb.net during debug.

I can go through that cycle as many times as I want.  So it seems like something in the solutions file is preventing edit during debug.

This problem is discussed here:

[VS 2013 ASP.NET can't modify the code while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069610/vs-2013-asp-net-cant-modify-the-code-while-debugging)

but not applying specifically to websites vs web applications.  The removal of the sou files is mentioned.

I built a small test website to demonstrate the problem, attached.   I'm hoping someone has seen the same behavior and figured out what might be done about it.  Or might be able to explain that I'm asking for something that's specifically not supposed to work.  (I've considered changing from website to web application however considering budget, time and skill set that's not a good option at this point --- looking better, though!)

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

webconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

=== page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server"
            ID="Label1"
            text="Whoa" />

        <asp:Button runat="server"
            ID ="Button1"
            text ="Test"
            />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

==== Code behind

```
Partial Class Test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Select Case Me.Label1.Text
            Case "Whoa"
                Me.Label1.Text = "Wow"
            Case "Wow"
                Me.Label1.Text = "Whoa"
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

=== solutions file

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.31101.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "0005_EnCTest(1)", "http://localhost:2039", "{4B173594-D476-4283-B656-A17B8972BABA}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_2039"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "D:\4500_TESTS\0005_EnCTest\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_2039\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_2039"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "D:\4500_TESTS\0005_EnCTest\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_2039\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "D:\4500_TESTS\0005_EnCTest\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {4B173594-D476-4283-B656-A17B8972BABA}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {4B173594-D476-4283-B656-A17B8972BABA}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I had answer, did not have answer